# How do I get an ImageView to work in an Android Studio layout

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am making an app that allows people to order meals from tablets at their table.

I have a LinearLayout for my header bar, one for the ListView and one for the ImageView. All of them seem to work except the ImageView

Here's the xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lo2"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_weight="0.13"
    android:background="#DDDDDD">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@mipmap/eMenu_Logo"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="eMenu"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:layout_gravity="right">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Your waiter today is Aubrey"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:src="@mipmap/aubrey" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="1291dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left">

        <ExpandableListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView2"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="868dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:id="@+id/">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:src="@mipmap/aubrey" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Help

Comment: *All of them seem to work except for the ImageView* show us a [MCVE]. Why is this tagged with `c++` ?

Comment: @t0mm13b Apologies

Comment: You have not add id " android:id="@+id/" " so you might be getting error in all of your linear layout. And also android:src="@mipmap/eMenu_Logo". You can't write capital letters name for your drawable. Instead you can write android:src="@mipmap/emenu_logo".

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:background="@drawable/aubrey"` or in your case, insted of drawable, mipmap folder

Answer (score 0):

You Have to edit the code for ImageView

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="68dp"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@mipmap/emenu_logo"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
```

And the source picture name in mipmap folder 
eMenu_Logo to emenu_logo

## resource dose not accept capital letter

Answer (score 0):

Your LinearLayout  orientation is vertical and you gave "matchparent" height to first child. So first child take whole space and your second child (That have image) out of the screen. So fix the height of your first child. Or you have to change the orientation from vertical to horizontal for parent LinearLayout and  reduce the width of first child.

I have change the orientation in below code:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="1291dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left">

        <ExpandableListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView2"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="868dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:id="@+id/abc">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```